# enable unbuntu pro asks to check internet connection, but the system is connected

Tags: server

When trying to enable Ubuntu pro on Ubuntu-server 22.04, it's stating that it unable to connect Ubuntu pro servers and to check the internet connection.  My internet connection is fine, I've been able to install apps and browse using Firefox.

Since I've been getting the error all day, I'm assuming there's something wrong with the GUI program. I've even checked online and I have 5 free slots on my account.

1. Is there a command line version of the tool?
2. Is this a known bug and is there a work around?

[image]

Comment: Troubleshooting and correcting a network-related problem is an appropriate question for AskUbuntu; we do that. Many Pro-specific problems cannot be answered here, as we are not Pro support. We are fellow users, not Canonical employees, and have no special insight into how the proprietary Pro product works.

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy the token from your Ubuntu Pro dashboard (https://ubuntu.com/pro)
2. Open a terminal:
   `sudo pro attach [YOUR_TOKEN]`

This will attach your system, but won't automatically set up esm or other services that you might want. Your next step should be those. See https://ubuntu.com/pro/tutorial for a tutorial leading you through the entire process.